# Le conditionnel de devoir: c'est une proposition ou une supposition

Tags: conditionnel

- Il mangerait du pain tous les jours.
- Il devrait manger du pain tous les jours.

La première phrase, si j'ai bien compris, est une supposition. C'est-à-dire : je ne suis pas sûr qu'il mange du pain tous les jours.

La deuxième phrase me pose problème. Est-ce aussi une supposition (comme la première) ou est-ce une proposition ? Je lui propose de manger du pain tous les jours ? Ou alors, faut-il le déterminer en fonction du contexte ?

Comment: Si tu pouvais donner un contexte plus précis pour tes exemples, il serait plus facile de te répondre.

Comment: @Nico S'il y a pas de contexte, le sens de la deuxième phrase ne peut pas être précisé?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La première est basée sur une condition :

*S'il y avait une boulangerie à côté, il mangerait du pain tous les jours.*

La deuxième est une suggestion, une recommandation :

*S'il veut prendre du poids, il devrait manger du pain tous les jours.*